# Powershell function - DLL call, function breaks when adding parameters to my function

Tags: powershell, dll

I have a function which is being called from another powershell script. When hardcoding my values, the function works as expected. But when I change my values to parameters, my function errors out saying the method with those overloads doesn't exist on the dll.

Extract from script that triggers the function:

```
Import-Module "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Utils.ps1" -Force
sampleFunction
```

Util function with logic:

```
function sampleFunction {
$ProjectId = "xyz";
$ClientID = "qdbe"
$loginURL       = "https://login.microsoftonline.com"

$tenantdomain = "mytenant"
$AADuserName = "myusername"
$AADpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "supersecret" -AsPlainText -Force
[string[]] $Scopes = "https://lcsapi.lcs.dynamics.com/.default"


# Load the MSAL assembly -- needed once per PowerShell session
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\myUser\MSAL\lib\microsoft.identity.client\4.18.0\lib\net45/Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll").fullname) | out-null
$global:app = $null

$ClientApplicationBuilder = [Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder]::Create($ClientID)
[void]$ClientApplicationBuilder.WithAuthority($("$loginURL/$tenantdomain"))
$global:app = $ClientApplicationBuilder.Build()


$AquireTokenParameters = $global:app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword($Scopes,$AADusername,$AADpassword)
$authResult = "";
try {
    $authResult = $AquireTokenParameters.ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
}
catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host "Found Error:" $ErrorMessage
}
    


$myvar = $authResult
#Do stuff with my access token

}
```

This works as expected.

But I don't want my values to be hardcoded off course, I want to pass them into the function. So I changed my function to take in parameters. But this breaks my `$global:app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword($Scopes,$AADusername,$AADpassword)` call

Call:

```
sampleFunction -ClientID $ClientID -tenantdomain $Tenantdomain -AADuserName $Username -AADpassword $AADpassword -ProjectId $ProjectId
```

Logic:

```
function sampleFunction {
    param (
        [string]$ProjectId,
        [string]$ClientID,
        [string]$tenantdomain,
        [string]$AADuserName,
        [string]$AADpassword
    )

$loginURL       = "https://login.microsoftonline.com"

$encryptedPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String  -AsPlainText -Force
[string[]] $Scopes = "https://lcsapi.lcs.dynamics.com/.default"


# Load the MSAL assembly -- needed once per PowerShell session
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\myUser\MSAL\lib\microsoft.identity.client\4.18.0\lib\net45/Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll").fullname) | out-null
$global:app = $null

$ClientApplicationBuilder = [Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder]::Create($ClientID)
[void]$ClientApplicationBuilder.WithAuthority($("$loginURL/$tenantdomain"))
$global:app = $ClientApplicationBuilder.Build()


$AquireTokenParameters = $global:app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword($Scopes,$AADusername,$encryptedPassword)
$authResult = "";
try {
    $authResult = $AquireTokenParameters.ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
}
catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host "Found Error:" $ErrorMessage
}
    


$myvar = $authResult
#Do stuff with my access token

}
```

But now my code fails with following error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword" and the argument count: "3".
At C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Utils.ps1:205 char:5
+     $AquireTokenParameters = $global:app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswo ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

I've tripled checked that all my variables contain the expected value via the debugger. the values passed are correct.

- $Scopes is hardcoded still
- $encryptedPassword is a valid
- Secure-String $AADusername is a valid String

Comment: What is the type signature of the ```AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword``` parameters? Note that when PowersShell says it can’t find an overload with the specified parameters it *sometimes* means it found more than one candidate but couldn’t choose between them...

Comment: Also, do you need to put the password variable in here? ```$encryptedPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String  -AsPlainText -Force```

Comment: @mclayton IEnumerable<string>, string, SecureString. If I remove the parameters from the function, the call works correctly with same values. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication.acquiretokenbyusernamepassword?view=azure-dotnet for the signature)